# Acer Aspire Nitro boot Windows 10 from usb 3.0

Tags: windows, boot, usb, bios, acer-aspire

I've been trying to get my asus aspire nitro to boot from usb. I have windows 10 pro installed on the portable hard drive. The nitro only comes with 3 usb 3.0 and no usb 2.0. I managed to get the drive to boot by setting Boot Mode to Legacy in my BIOS but when that is set I can't manage to boot from the PC's internal hard drive. I've tried all ports but the Boot Option Menu won't show and option for USB when Boot Mode is set to UEFI? Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: If you are trying to change the boot order, while CPM ( i.e. Legacy Mode ) isn't enable, you do that by telling windows to boot into the [`Advance Startup `](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2294-advanced-startup-options-boot-windows-10-a.html) which will allow you to then change the boot order.

Comment: Sorry I've managed to get it to boot in legacy mode. But when in UEFI mode it isnt detected as bootable. Only shows my internal hard drive. Even when I have USB HDD and USB FDD at the top of the list. When I'm in CPM I can boot the USB but the Windows 10 install on my HD wont boot when I select the HD

Comment: If it isn't being detected as bootable then the image on the disk does not have the required EFI drivers.

Comment: How do I update my local windows 10 install to have the required EFI drivers?

Comment: You boot to the installation disk in non-compatibility mode and install Windows.  If your partition type is GPT then you have already done that.  You need to verify the EFI drivers are on the external disk on the EFI partition.